# My .NET5 app deployed on Heroku sends Emails with question marks instead of letters with punctuation

Tags: .net, email, heroku, character-encoding, charset

When I send it from local environment, i receive email correctly, but when i send it from app deployed on heroku I receive question marks instead of "í","á,"é","ě" ect.

I tried to log it and this fault is made before email is send to SMTP server. So i think it could be any problem with Heroku server charset setting.

Does anyone have had simillar problem ?

My class:

```
public Task SendEmailAsync(string SendTo, string subject, string body)
    {
        using SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient()
        {
            Host = "email.active24.com",
            Port = 587,
            EnableSsl = true,
            UseDefaultCredentials = false,
            Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("info@xxx.cz", "xxx")
        };

        MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
        message.From = new MailAddress("info@xxx.cz");
        message.To.Add(SendTo);
        message.Subject = subject;
        message.IsBodyHtml = true;
        message.Body = $"<h1>{body}</h1>";
        message.HeadersEncoding = Encoding.Default;
        message.BodyEncoding = Encoding.Default;
        message.SubjectEncoding = Encoding.Default;
       
        logger.Info(message.Body);
    
        try
        {
            smtpClient.Send(message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //TODO handle error
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

Thank you in advance :-)

Comment: I'd guess that `SmtpDeliveryFormat` property of `smtpClient` defaults to `SevenBit` (0). Try `International` (1)? And/or set `message.BodyTransferEncoding` (see the `System.Net.Mime.TransferEncoding` enumeration).

Comment: thank you very much, I added smtpClient.DeliveryFormat = SmtpDeliveryFormat.International; and message.BodyTransferEncoding = TransferEncoding.Base64; but without any change. :(